# Adjacency matrix of a network to Distance matrix (Two -Hop)

Tags: matlab, adjacency-matrix

I have the following code for generating an adjacency matrix for a network.
How do I go about creating a distance matrix (Probably a two hop matrix)from this output.

```
function  adj = AdjMatrixLattice4( N, M )
    % Size of adjacency matrix
    MN = M*N;
    adj = zeros(MN,MN);

      for i=1:N
        for j=1:N
            A = M*(i-1)+j;          %Node # for (i,j) node
            if(j<N)                
                B = M*(i-1)+j+1;    %Node # for node to the right
                C = M*(i-1)+j+2;
                D = M*(i-1)+j+2;
                adj(A,B) = 1;
                adj(B,A) = 1;
                adj(A,C) = 1;
                adj(C,A) = 1;
                adj(A,D) = 1;
                adj(D,A) = 1;
            end
            if(i<M)
                B = M*i+j;  
                C = M*i+j+1;    %Node # for node below
                D = M*i+j;
                adj(A,B) = 1;       
                adj(B,A) = 1;
                adj(A,C) = 1;
                adj(C,A) = 1;
                adj(A,D) = 1;
                adj(D,A) = 1;
            end            
        end
    end    
end
```

The output for the following program is

> > AdjMatrixLattice4(3,3)

ans =

```
 0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0     0
 1     0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0     0     0
 1     1     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
 1     1     0     1     0     1     1     1     1     0
 0     1     1     1     1     0     0     0     1     1
 0     0     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     0
 0     0     0     1     1     0     1     0     1     1
 0     0     0     0     1     1     1     1     0     0
 0     0     0     0     0     1     0     1     0     0
```

Comment: are there only zero and ones? or in an another case it could change?

Comment: They will have only 1s and 0s.